# What is the best architecture for Enterprise application based on Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am going to build an Enterprise application using `Angular2` with `Typescript`, this mean the application will have have seven embedded applications in it, and a big team will work to build it, so i am looking for the best architecture to developing an application like this (Based on `Angular2` ) that make the process much easier for adding and editing in this application.

Comment: what sort of answer are you looking for beyond the typical 1. split your user interface into small, self contained components, 2. let your components handle UI related stuff and move other logic into services 3. try to split your components into smart vs presentational components etc ?

Comment: yes the application will be having many modules, but I also need to know the best way of organizing  enterprise solution files in order to preserve components decoupling.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to answer this question, because ***best*** is subjective, but have a look at this article: [Scalable Single-Page Application Architecture](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/04/10/scalable-javascript-single-page-app-angular2-application-architecture/).

Minko, the author, also did [a talk about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9D5JeVClBs).

My advice:

- Keep everything open - make service stubs and use them in your components while providing real services at module level.
- Use self-contained features - make sure your feature modules work in any context and outside your app.
- Use Redux - @ngrx/store and it's state management are great for larger projects

Answer (score 0):

When you use Angular you follows Angular overall architecture as a whole already. What you should focus on is how to reach true modularity when managing modules between different applications.

1. You should investigate how angular modules work and how
   functionalities can be split into separate modules so different team can work independently from each other.
2. How to manage imports and exports between these modules to assemble
       the whole application. For example using `npm` for deploying your teams module and packages.